# How to draw on Camera Preview

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-canvas, android-camera-intent

for some time I've been working on this app, that allows user to take photos. The interesting thing about it, is that there should be some lines drawn over camera preview. The problem is that I'm not quite sure how to do this. I do have codes to initiate camera and to draw line, but I do not know how to merge them.

I use this code to initiate camera on button click:

```
  initCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Starting a new Intent
            /*Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextScreen);*/
             count++;
            String file = dir+count+".jpg";
            File newfile = new File(file);
            try {
                newfile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {}       

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);



        }
    });
```

And here's how I usually draw lines:

```
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);



    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, conf); 
    canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    p.setStrokeWidth(5);
    canvas.drawLine(0, height/2, width, height/2, p);
```

Comment: Well, the problem is, that you can not manipulate another apps output (with the first code you are starting the camera app). If you want to be able to draw over the camera preview, you basically have to implement your own camera function into your app. Look around the internet for tutorials.

Comment: I had already done my own camera through Fragment and Activity, Listener and Preview. The reason it didn't work, is because it does not have focus option. I suppose I did it with http://www.androidzeitgeist.com/2012/10/displaying-camera-preview-instant.html tutorial. But thanks, I'll change direction of my work.

Comment: Okay. I've looked around for alternative and as far as I can tell, I need to add focus feature to my custom camera. I didn't find a decent tutorial for this, frankly I didn't find any tutorial.

Comment: what about a search on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+camera+focus

Comment: There are similar questions. But none gives a good solid explanation of how to use focus. Moreover - most of them use auto focus.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an overlay to draw on top of the live camera preview. The overlay is a child class of the surface the preview is drawn on. The preview class looks something like this:

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,    Camera.PreviewCallback 
    {

        Preview(Context context) 
        {
            super(context);
            SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
            SurfaceHolder mHolder;

            mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(PreviewContext);
            addView(mSurfaceView);

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            PreviewCameraOverlay = new CameraOverlay(context);
            addView(PreviewCameraOverlay);
        }
        // Additional functions like:
        // surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
        // onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera pCamera)
        // etc.
    }

        protected class CameraOverlay extends View
        {
            public CameraOverlay(Context context)
            {
                super(context);

                setWillNotDraw(false);
                setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                setAlpha(1f);
                OverlayPaint = new Paint[PaintColors];
             }
          // Additional functions:
          // onDraw(Canvas canvas)
          // onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)


         }
```

From your main activity you would call:  `Preview CameraPreview = new Preview(this);` and draw whatever it is you want to draw from CameraOverlay's `onDraw()`.

Comment: Could you please explain the answer a bit? Because as far as I understand, all I need to do is create a `Preview.java`, paste your code and add `Preview CameraPreview = new Preview(this);` under `startActivityForResult`. 1. It doesn't work. 2. Could you provide imports as well?

Comment: Providing a complete example of working code to draw on top of a live camera preview, is too big a task for the space available here. This is a tutorial on creating a live camera preview: http://www.edumobile.org/android/camera-preview-example-in-android-programming/  Once you have that working, you can add an overlay to preview as indicated above. The overlay class is pretty simple, with only three native functions: the constructor, onDraw(Canvas canvas), and onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec). Of course you will want to add some functions that define what to draw.